# Kotlin - nullable property default to null value

Tags: properties, kotlin, nullable

Suppose I define a class with a **nullable** property

```
class ABC {
   var myProperty: String? = null
}
```

Is there a way to default it to null value?
Maybe something similar to SCALA?

```
var myProperty: String? = _  // compilation error
```

or simply:

```
var myProperty: String?  // compilation error
```

I know we could have used a **lateinit** variable that from Kotlin 1.2 can be later checked for initilization like so:

```
lateinit var myProperty: String

if (::myProperty.isInitialized) {
   //value is not-null
}
```

So is lateinit the preferred way? Is defaulting to null value possible or it's omitted on purpose?

Comment: You defaulted it to null right here: `var myProperty: String? = null`. `lateinit` doesn't default it to anything and the explicit check with `isInitialized` is a hack that is against the intent behind the feature of `lateinit`.

Comment: In other words, it's not possible you have to use `late init` (which can throw an exception on early access) or explicitly init the variable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `var myProperty: String? = null` defaults to null but I find `= null` redundant and was trying to simplify the code

Comment: So you're not asking about defaulting to user-provided values, but about a built-in, implicit default value. Kotlin's general mantra is "be explicit" and this is one example.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  I just needed **String?** which defaults to **null** without expicitly saying so. But **lateinit** seems closest to my needs. Thanks

Comment: You can also use optional variable. like val javaNullable: Optional<String> = Optional.ofNullable("java"), for more https://dzone.com/articles/kotlin-null-safety-for-the-optional-experience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no.
Unlike some other languages (Scala, Go), Kotlin doesn't assume it knows best what the default value for the type is (who said that it should be 0 for int anyway?)

Comment: "who said that it should be 0 for int anyway?" - logic ? :)

Comment: `0` has a lot of meaning to it. If you work with data, the difference between `null` and `0` is huge. Say you make a record of sales, and a `unitsSold` value somehow didn't get set because of a connection issue, do you want to go with `0` (which implies nothing got sold) or `null` (implying the data is unknown)? When working with counters, defaulting to `0` makes sense, but there are a lot more use-cases out there. It depends on the goal of the language: save keystrokes or make dev's think about their defaults. I guess Kotlin went for the latter :)

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin intentionally requires you to initialize all properties explicitly. There is no shorthand syntax. For a property of a nullable type, the preferred way is not to use `lateinit`, but to declare it with a `null` initializer.

The `isInitialized` method for `lateinit` properties is designed to handle complex cases like cleanup of resources; it's not intended to be used as a replacement for a `null` check for users who want to save on writing `= null` as part of a property declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare a global function

```
fun nullString(): String? {
    return null
}
```

and use it like

```
class ABC {
   var myProperty = nullString()
}
```

Since there is only one null reference in the language, a global variable will also work

```
var nullString : String? = null

class ABC {
   var myProperty = nullString
}
```

P.S. - 
unfortunately the spacial characters like '_' are reserved in Kotlin so you can't use it to name your variable and create `var myProperty = _`

Comment: Kotlin devs should consider adding '_' as variable value initializer to "type default value" i.e. 0 for int, null for String etc.